# How can I trim a YouTube video link to extract its ID only?

Tags: kotlin

I need to get video Id's from user inputs.

The problem is that you tube links could come in two formats.

Either:
https://youtu.be/gzy7KB-yUYE
Or:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gzy7KB-yUYE

How could I extract this 'gzy7KB-yUYE' only, no matter what input did the user enter?

Comment: what did you try so far? which documentation did you consult so far?

Comment: for first case, try ```url.split("/")[1]``` and for second case, try ```url.split("=")[1]```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably you won't find "a nice solution". You can do something like this:

```
fun extractId(text: String) : String{

    val parts = text.split("/")

    if(text.contains("https://youtu.be/")){
        return parts.get(parts.size -1)
    }

    if(text.contains("https://www.youtube.com/") && text.contains("watch?v=")){
        return (parts.get(parts.size -1)).replace("watch?v=", "")
    }

    return "";
}
```

Comment: how do you know that there is a `String` coming? could it be an `URL`? an `URI`? something completely different? Depending on what is coming, the solution may vary and may effectively become easier?

Comment: I did mention that it isn't "a nice solution", but if he has just two versions of strings, that could help. Also, possibly, he could deal with vimeo video or something else...

Comment: what I wanted to say: before the OP shows any code, it is all just guessing... of course that might work out this way... but who would use such a function, if an `URL` is used already? you could then just say `url.host == "youtu.be"`, etc.

Comment: I understand you, you're right, but this will be enough if he deals with just these two types of urls.